# Php - How to make an efficient user online and offline determiner ?

Tags: php, mysql, database, chat

I have 1000 users and they have people to a peer like a G+ circle but i want to know if a person is online to chat but I have tried to update a chat database with a timestamp and its not as efficient I want to know if there is another way even if complex but efficeint Ideas pleas

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing **anything** about what you are doing.

Comment: you can check if there is an active session if they are stored in a db and are destroyed e.g. when the browser is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WebSockets. 
There is this jQuery plugin allowing you to use Websockets while gracefully degrading for non-supporting browsers. On the PHP side, there is https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/  class which seems to be the most widely used for PHP WS servers.

Comment: Good Idea. The question is about 4 years old. But I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more what you mean by "this" in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Create a MySQL table with the memory storage engine. Let's say you have 3 columns - id, username, last_seen. Set the ID as primary index, then you simply update last_seen when the user does something (or via Ajax), and then you just fetch last_seen (eg. via Ajax) and compare it with the current timestamp. I doubt it could be simpler than that.